# Using jsn_totext() and xbuf_empty()

Tags: json, parsing, g-wan

Consider the following simple program (run on gwan v4.3.14):

```
xbuf_t buf;
xbuf_init(&buf);
xbuf_cat(&buf, "{\"num\":-1}");            // simple json string
jsn_t *jrec = jsn_frtext(buf.ptr, "rec");  // parse it
jsn_t *jnum = jsn_byname(jrec, "num",1);   // look for the element
jsn_updt(jnum, 2);                         // change the value to positive 2
xbuf_empty(&buf);                          // reuse the buffer
puts(jsn_totext(&buf, jrec, 0));           // lets take a look
```

The expected output is `{"num":2}` but it turned out to be `{"num":-2}`.

Somehow, `jsn_totext()` reused the emptied xbuffer and overwrote the location of '1' with '2'. But if I were to do `jsn_update(jnum, 100)`, the output would be correct.

Is this a bug or did I misunderstand the functionality of `xbuf_empty()` ?

I am asking the quesiton because using `xbuf_reset()` instead of `xbuf_empty()` makes this code work as expected.

Comment: BTW, I'm really impress with the performance of gwan. If not for the frequent restart of the application in daemon mode, I might consider it for serious production deployment.

Comment: These system incompatibilities have been fixed in v4.5+ and today's release is v5.5 (one year later: the first version number is the year, the second the month). We will publicly release a major update later this year but, to prevent other gratuitous system modifications to spoil the game, not before we ship our G-WAN-based Cloud services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost answered the question: the problem in your code comes from the (mis)use of the `xbuf_empty()` function.

Let's explain why:

The manual explains that `jsn_totext()` stores the output in an xbuffer and that you then have to *"[call xbuf_free(text) when you are done with the text](http://gwan.ch/api#json)"*.

It means that the destination xbuffer is supposed to be ***unallocated*** yet as `jsn_totext()` will allocate it.

You said that using `xbuf_reset()` works. This si because this call is a [deprecated alias of the `xbuf_init()` function](http://gwan.ch/api#xbuffers).

Your confusion came from the fact that `xbuf_reset()` is too close to `xbuf_empty()`... and that's why we renamed it `xbuf_init()` (a few years ago).

Now, your question is raising an interesting question which is why we did not think to either reuse or re-init already allocated xbuffers passed to `jsn_totext()`.

We did not do it because we obviously did not think someone would reuse the same buffer. But as your report shows, it may happen, so we will make the modification to help other users avoid the same trap.

This is this kind of relevant feedback that makes products better as time goes. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I presume that re-using xbuf will be of better performance as it does not need to run a round of freeing memory and allocating memory again. Using just xbuf_empty() seems to work for all other functions - except of course, jsn_totext().

Comment: Incidentally, I can get jsn_totext() to output the right string without unallocating xbuf. Simply:
   xbuf_clear(&buf);
   xbuf_empty(&buf);
Naturally, xbuf_clear() will take up considerable CPU cycles if the buffer is big.

Comment: Right. If my answer makes sense to you, please 'accept' it. This will help others to find the solution of this problem.